# How to have a smooth animation in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I have created a splash activity where I animate a TextView. It is coming from outside the activity inside and it remains centered. The problem is that in a ConstraintLayout is not smooth. This is what I have tried:

```
Animation leftToCenterAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_center);
findViewById(R.idleft_text_view).startAnimation(leftToCenterAnimation);
```

This is how my `left_to_center` file looks like:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true">
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="198%" />
</set>
```

How to have a smooth animation?

Comment: Try doing with motion layout.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi Ok, give it a try. Is there any orher solution?

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi I only want to animate a TextView from left to center not to create a animated layout on swipe. Is this even possible?

Comment: May be This Link can help you. https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50